# Rails 3 - Merge query options

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, merge

I have this method form a Rails 2.3.4 app:

```
def self.find_all_colored(query, options={})
  finder_options = {:conditions => "color = #{query}"}.merge(options)
  Car.find(:all, finder_options)
end
```

With which I can do:

```
Car.find_all_colored("red", :limit => 5)
```

But I am having a really bad time trying to get that to work in Rails 3.1.1, by now I can make it work but without the .merge(options), if I add that part:

```
def self.find_all_colored(query, options={})
  Car.where("color = #{query}").merge(options)
end
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `default_scoped?' for {:limit=>5}:Hash
```

I've googled and searched in stackoverflow.com but no luck...thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
def self.find_all_colored(query, options={})
  self.all({:conditions => {:color => query}}.merge(options))
end
```

Comment: I'm sorry Gazler, it actually doesn't work when looking at the generated SQL, options is not being included.

Comment: Are you on Rails 3.1?  I was testing on a rails 3 app.  http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gazler. Yes, we are upgrading a 2.3.4 app to 3.1.1. From the link you posted: "In short, passing options hash containing :conditions, :include, :joins, :limit, :offset, :order, :select, :readonly, :group, :having, :from, :lock to any of the ActiveRecord provided class methods, is now deprecated."

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot for your time Gazler, you deserve a cookie.